# using compass in Windows Phone emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to create application for WP7 using data from compass sensor.
I've found this example: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202974(v=vs.92).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202974%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

It works fine (tested on device), but I'm curious, if it is possible to test it in emulator. If I try to rotate device within the emulator (accelerometer tab), nothing happens.

Any ideas how to test it in emulator?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Phone 7 emulator can simulate accelerometer and GPS, but not compass. You will have to write your own compass simulator. This is quite easy to do, just follow the same kind of approach developers used before the emulator simulated accelerometer. See:

[Windows Phone 7 Emulator: Simulating the accelerometer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/velloso/archive/2010/09/24/windows-phone-7-emulator-simulating-the-accelerometer.aspx)

http://wp7accelerometerkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: Problem is I cannot use functions like compass.Start() and others, becase I get InvalidOperationException (Sensor is not preset on this platform), so writing own emulator would be way more difficult than for accelerometer which is preset.

Comment: @luccio - Colin is recommending you do something _similar_ to sample accelerometer emulation, but for the compass.

Comment: I do understand, but for now I ended with testing on device. It would take a lot of time to implement compass emulation.